# redirect 301 all link except some links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want redirect301 all old link that have .htm extenstion in end of url  to a new url example.com/fa. but I have some exception that has .htm exception in their url which should link to corresponding links. I write following code in .htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(کربن\sمولکولارسیو.htm)$ fa/مولکولارسیو/62-cms-کربن-مولکولارسیو [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(مولکولارسیو.htm)$ fa/مولکولارسیو [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(آلومینا\sاکتیو.htm)$ fa/مولکولارسیو/60-آلومینا-اکتیو [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*.htm)$ fa/ [R=301,L]
```

Three first link work properly. but another link result:

```
404 Page note found
```

With the last regex I want to link another url to example.com/fa.
What is solution?

Comment: redirect 301 with htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use joomla cms and set rewrite url setting to on.
For above reasons in .htaccess file there are many setting about redirect that set for existed files and request to non-exist files (url) results 404 error message. Instead put my code to end of .htaccess I put these in the beginning of file. By this act, joomla setting in .htaccess file go after my code and my code has no conflict with previous setting.

> Thanks for no answering which led to find solution by my own.